# How to get paginated child lists from OneToMany unidrectional Parent using findByParentCode

Tags: jpa, pagination, spring-data

I have onetomany unidrirectional parent -  child.
I am fetching the child list using parent.
How do i apply pagination on the list of child records?
For Ex: Parent P has Child C1,C2,C3..C20
i do findByParentCode(Code) returns the Parent object with Child list in it.    But i need to get the paginated list of the child.
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query your child object's table using the parent code field in the child object i.e the foreign key to the Parent table something like:

```
Page<Child> findByParentId(Long parentId, Pageable pageRequest);
```

You can paginate the query results by using Spring Data JPA pagination support. Create an instance of [PageRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html) class with the pageNumber, size and sorting if need be, and iterate over the pages as shown below

```
Page<Child> page = null;
do {
    Pageable nextPageable = page != null ? page.nextPageable() : new PageRequest(0, pageSize);
    page = childService.findByParentId(parentId, nextPageable);
    processPage(page);
} while (page.hasNext());
```

Comment: hi Abishek, Thank you for your answer. I dint think this way.Its a good option.  All i wanted to find from the parent repo.So there is no way i can achieve this using parentRepository. Creating custom repo methods - wil it help.

Comment: Hi user1352862,  dynamic paging is currently not supported with @OneToMany collections on top of JPA . It should be possible to patch Hibernate for this behavior but obviously it won't be a trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

I have done pagination for the child list (which does not know its parent)

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "select s.chilidList from Parent s where s.ParentCode = :ParentCode");
        query.setParameter("ParentCode", ParentCode);
        query.setFirstResult(pageIndex);
        query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
```