# Spring Data JPA. Pagination for child entities

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, one-to-many

I'm using Spring Data JPA with Spring boot version 1.3.6.RELEASE with in-memory database.

I'm wondering how to **paginate the child entities** from a parent entity.
Setting fetch to **LAZY** is not a solution for me.

Here is the use case :

1. *Parent* has an **unidirectional** oneToMany relation with Child *entity*.
2. The number of *Child* for one *Parent* can reach 100,000 (LAZY is not a solution)
3. I don't want to fetch all the child to do the pagination (For CPU and Memory reason)

Here is a code sample :

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> childs;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}

public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer>{}
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Integer>{}
```

I've tried this in the Parent repository unsuccessfully :

```
Page<Child> findById(int id, Pageable pageable);
```

This returns a Parent entity, not a Child entity.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Well, since you're looking for child entities, that method should be in the ChildRepository, and it should be named findByParent, and return children associated with a given parent entity. Something like `select child from Parent p inner join p.children child where p = :parent`.

Comment: Will it work even if the relation is unidirectional? I'll give it  a try.

Comment: The same problem  I am trying to solve without any luck. You can answer your question if able to solve it. [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582224/how-to-get-paginated-child-lists-from-onetomany-unidrectional-parent-using-findb)

Comment: I just did what @JBNizet mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample of code that can fetch the child entities knowing the parent.
Note that this query will return a paginated result of Child.

```
 /**
  * Find Child entities knowing the Parent.
  */
  @Query("select child from Parent p inner join p.childs child where p = :parent")
  public Page<Child> findBy(@Param("parent") Parent parent, Pageable pageable);
```

And you can use it like this :

```
Page<Child> findBy = repo.findBy(parent, new PageRequest(page, size));
```

Comment: I tried doing some thing similar , could you please share some inputs on this post ?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64491315/4005379

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parent is called "Parent" you can also do something like that:

`repo.findAllByParent(parent, pageable)`;