# Spring JPA Pagination on Sub-Entities using Dynamic Projection

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-projections

How to Paginate on the ChildEntity from a ParentEntity (unidirectional oneToMany) via Dynamic Projection. Heres my code sample which works while paginating on Parent .

***Repository*** -
I tried this, looking this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46055857/4005379) , but it throws

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dumyRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.api.repo.DumyRepository.findByDumyIdIn(java.util.Set,java.lang.Class,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) but parameter 'Optional[dumyIds]' not found in annotated query 'select child from ParentEntity p inner join p.childEntities child where p = :type'!

```
 `@Query("select child from ParentEntity p inner join p.childEntities child where p = :type")
<T> Page<T> findByDumyIdIn(Set<String> demoIds, @Param("type") Class<T> type, Pageable pagable);`
```

May be i'm missing something here ?

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends
        JpaRepository<ParentEntity, Long> {

    <T> Page<T> findByDumyIdIn(Set<String> dumyIds, Class<T> type,Pageable pagable);

}
```

***Projection Interfaces***

```
public interface ChildDetailsView {
    String getDumyId();
    List<ChildEntity> getChildEntities();
}

public interface ParentDetailsView {
    Long getId();
    String getDumyId();
    String getDc();
    String getComp();
}
```

***Service Classes***

```
public Map<String, ParentDetailsView> findParentMapping(Set<String> dumyIds, Pageable pageable) {
        return this.dsRepo.findByDumyIdIn(demoIds,ParentDetailsView.class,pageable)
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap( k  -> k.getDumyId(), v->v));
    }


 public Map<String, ChildDetailsView> findChildMapping(Set<String> dumyIds,
                                                              Pageable pageable) {
        return this.dsRepo.findByDumyIdIn(demoIds, ChildDetailsView.class,pageable)
                .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap( k  -> k.getDumyId(), v->v));
        }
```

***Entity Classes***

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity{
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 31)
    private String dumyId;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 31)
    private String dc;

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 31)
    private String comp;

    @OneToMany
    private List<ChildEntity> childEntities;
}

@Entity
public class ChildEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NonNull
    private Sting name;
}
```

Comment: [See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192091/spring-data-jpa-pagination-for-child-entities)

Comment: @Blake, thanks for responding and I did take a look at the post. Updated my post above with the exception.

Comment: I wonder if you'd still get that exception if you made the repository method concrete return a concrete type (Parent) rather than a generic

Comment: Yeah , The repository method would return one of the two mentioned Projection Interfaces based on the call from the service classes.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `ChildDetailView`? Why do you have the argument `Set<String> demoIds` in the method, when that is not used by the query? I don't see the relationship between the code you showed and the response you claim to implement. So far this looks like a perfect dupe to me, but also I'm confused.

Comment: @JensSchauder, Thanks for commenting. The purpose of  ChildDetailView is to findChildMapping() , (see the service class) . Here I want to paginate on the list of ChildEntities coming from this projection, which I'm unable to . How should I achieve that ?